# Navigation in UISearchController iOS11

Tags: swift, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to implement the same behavior like in WhatsApp. I go into Chats pull down, type in my Search and a new TableView is presented with the searchresults in it.

No problem up to this point. It looks like this:

```
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: UITableViewController())

 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 definesPresentationContext = true

 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
 }
```

Now the hairy part: When I click on a result I want it to be shown like in a UINavigationController. Just like in WhatsApp. And when I click back I want to see my search with the results in it.

I tried all kind of stuff. Embed the searchResultsController in a UINavigationController. Playing around with definesPresentationContext, and so on. Maybe someone of you got a solution for this.

I do'nt want the searchResults to be displayed right in place for performance reasons. There has to be a solution with all results in the searchResultsController.

I am soooooooo thankful for any suggestions and solutions how to solve this.

Comment: Can you give some images for your situation?

Comment: I added some images.

Comment: Can you show me `didSelectRow` method?

Comment: i set it all up with storyboard. This is the method: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEntry", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
    }

Comment: What i forgot to say: In my example is the resultsviewcontroller embedded in a UINavigationController.

Comment: Actually, it’s complicated ;). Can you create a debug repo and give me the link? I want to debug it by myself

Comment: Yeah it is ^^. Here is a sample repository :D: https://github.com/dazeili/SearchResultsController

Comment: When i click on a cell while searching, nothing happens. Please update your repo.

Comment: Oh forgot that. Is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY I FOUND THE ANSWER!!! 
The solution is: Create a subclass for your searchResultsController, when you instantiate the controller pass a reference of the UINavigationController to it. On selecting the cell you call this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // yourController is the UIViewController to show your stuff
    if let yourController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourController"){
        // navController is the reference to the navController of the controller where you performed the search
        navController?.pushViewController(yourController, animated: true)
    }
}
```